# Approaches For Deeply Extending a Parser Library

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming, parser-combinators

The material on parser combinators I have found covers building up complex parsers though composition, but I would like to know if there are any good approaches for defining parsers by tweaking the composed parsers of a library without completely duplicating the original library's logic.

For example, here is a simplified CSV parser defined in [Real world Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html)

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

csvFile = endBy line eol
line = sepBy cell (char ',')
cell = many (noneOf ",\n")
eol = char '\n'
```

Assuming `csvFile` is defined in one library, can another library create its own CSV parser using a custom version of the `cell` parser without having to rewrite the `line` and `csvFile` parsers as well? Can the source library be rewritten to make this possible? This is simple enough for the CSV parser but I am interested in a broadly applicable solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally you'd need to abstract over the signature of the components you want to replace. For instance, in the CSV example we'd need to extend the type of `csvFile` to allow us to slot in a custom  `cell`.

```
line cell = sepBy cell (char ',')
csvFile cell = endBy (line cell) eol
```

Obviously this gets unwieldy quickly. We can package all of the extension points desired up into a dictionary however and pass it around

```
data LanguageDefinition =
  LanguageDefinition { cell :: Parser Cell 
                     , ...
                     }
```

Then we parameterize the entire parser combinator library over this `LanguageDefinition`

```
data Parsers = Parsers { line :: Parser Line, csvFile :: Parser [Line], ... }

mkParsers :: LanguageDefinition -> Parsers
```

This is exactly the approach taken by the generalized Token parsing modules of Parsec: see [Text.Parsec.Token](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.5/docs/Text-Parsec-Token.html) and [Text.Parsec.Language](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.5/docs/Text-Parsec-Language.html).

---

Even more generic approaches can be taken which abstract more and more things into the dictionary that's getting passed around. Effectively this becomes an object- or OCaml module oriented method of organizing code and can be very effective.

The folk Expression Problem states that there's a tension between introducing more functionality and introducing more variants. In this case, you're asking for a new variant so you need to fix the functionality (and list it all out in a dictionary). This will open a path to introduce new variants.